# Error when trying to calculate the sum: Python 3

Tags: python

```
## Open the file and make a list
file = [line.rstrip() for line in open("numbers.txt", 'r')]
for number in file:
## Declare some variables
        smallest = min(file)
        largest = max(file)
        counter = len(file)
        total = sum(file)
## Display the values
print("Smallest: " + smallest)
print("Largest: " + largest)
print("Count: " + str(counter))
print("Sum: " + str(total))
```

I'm getting this error when trying to calculate the sum. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each item in `file` is a string representing a line in your file. Whatever you have in there, you can't call `sum()` on strings. If they were numbers, you then wouldn't be able to call `len()`, as that doesn't work on numbers. You're also calculating a new `smallest`, `largest`, `counter`, and `sum` for each line, so it would only save results for the most recent one if it even worked.

The precise reason for the error message is that `sum()` works by adding each item from whatever iterable was passed to it to an initial value. The default initial value is `0`. Therefore, it first tries to add e.g. `0 + '12'` and fails because you're adding an `int + str`. You can pass a custom initial value, e.g. `sum([[1],[2]], [])` to produce `[1, 2]`, but it doesn't work with strings, because you need to use `str.join` for that. It will even say this in a specific error message if you try e.g. `sum(['a', 'b'], '')`.

Let's assume your file has one number per line. You could then cast them all to `float`s, and not need to make an explicit loop over them. We'll also simply pass multiple arguments to `print()`, using the default separator of a single space, so that we don't have to do any string casting or concatenation. It's also better to use the `with` construct as a context manager, which automatically closes file handles when the block ends:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    numbers = list(map(float, f))
print("Smallest:", min(numbers))
print("Largest:", max(numbers))
print("Count:", len(numbers))
print("Sum:", sum(numbers))
```